# referenced memory conditionally modified in recursive loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, recursion, pass-by-reference

I have two structs and a function

```
struct nodeT {
bool last;
string attribute1;
string attribute2;
string attribute3;
vector<charT> leafs;
};

struct charT {
char character;
nodeT *next;
};

void addNode(nodeT *n, string stringy, string &attribute1, string &attribute2, string &attribute3)
{
   if (stringy=="") {
      w->last=true;
      return;
   } else {
      if (n->last==true) {
          attribute1=n->attribute1; //these attribute fields were given values earlier
          attribute2=n->attribute2;
          attribute3=n->attribute3;
      }
      addNode(n, stringy.substr(1), attribute);
   }
}
```

And `addNode` is called with

```
string test="";
addNode(root, "wordy", test, test, test);
```

The problem is the attribute reference `string &attribute` is not changed to 5, it continues the next call with the `""` value.

I tried making it a pointer reference `*attribute->n->attribute`
And tied a reference `&attribute = n->attribute`
These were shots in the dark and did not work.

EDIT: `addNode` should have been called with individual memory references.

```
string test1="";
string test2="";
string test3="";
addNode(root, "wordy", test1, test2, test3);
```

Comment: Compile with level 4 warnings (`/W4`) and see what warnings you get.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler just spit at the line `string attribute = 5;`? See http://ideone.com/xVg0C, but that's gcc...

Comment: I think I found the problem - following the advice of these comments. I created two values `int j = 0` and then `string temp = ""` for the initial call (there are 5 attributes) and then used these two for all five.

Comment: `addNode` references the undefined identifier `w`, so this code won't even compile.  `string attribute = 5;` also makes no sense -- `5` is an integer not a string and can't be converted to one implicitly.

Comment: yes, my bad example, the code is a mess and I just wanted to post a simple example but goofed it

Comment: who gets the answer? the two answers that addressed the `""` memory shoudl get the check since they were close. It was actually that I used `string = temp` for several references then tried to modify those references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers made by the contributors helped lead me to the answer but they have been hitting answers slightly off from the issue.

For setup, function uses structs `nodeT` and `charT`
and is was called with the equivalent of

```
   root is defined globally in the class
   string wordy = "hello";
   string test="";
   addNode(root, "wordy", test, test, test);
```

`addNode` should have been called with individual memory references.

```
string test1="";
string test2="";
string test3="";
addNode(root, "wordy", test1, test2, test3);
```

So when later when attributes 1, 2 and 3 are changed with unique values, there is a corresponding unique memory for each.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initializing `attribute` in a constructor?

```
struct nodeT {
   bool last;
   string attribute;
   vector<charT> leafs;
   nodeT() : attribute("5") {}
 };
```

Your code looks somewhat, but not entirely, unlike Java... :-)

Comment: funny, I learned java before C++ but do not remember java anymore.

Comment: yes, attribute has values from an earlier pass through the tree. I posted a simplified example here and did not fully capture what I have

Comment: no, I have not tried initializing with a constructor but I will remember that approach for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

No of args for function declaration and function call don't match and function dosnt have variable arg. It should not clear compilation hurdels also.

Comment: I corrected the error in the question, there are three parameters for attribute - I used a simplified example and lost some of the context of the question